# Getting Json dictionary/list values python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a json file with a dictionary, and lists inside that dictionary

```
{"Dogs": [["spot"], 1], "Cats": [["whiskers"], 1], "fish": [["bubbles", "lefty", "tank", "goldie"], 4], "elephant": [["tiny", "spring"], 2], "zebra": [[], 1], "gazelle": [["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "gold", "silver"], 6]}
```

There's more in the dictionary but from this example you can see the format.

```
with open('myfile.json', 'r') as myfile:
json_data = json.load(myfile)
for e,([v], z) in json_data.items():
  print e, v, z
```

This gives me a

```
too many values to unpack error.
```

I want the output to look like

```
dogs spot 1
cats whiskers 1
```

Comment: What do you want to happen for fish? You cant unpack into a list.

Comment: What should the output be when there are multiple things in the lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you want all animal names (?) output

```
...
for e, (v, z) in json_data.items():
    print('%s %s %d' % (e.lower(), ' '.join(v), z))
```

outputs

```
gazelle red blue green yellow gold silver 6
fish bubbles lefty tank goldie 4
cats whiskers 1
zebra  1
elephant tiny spring 2
dogs spot 1
```

Answer (score 0):

much simpler since the value is always going to be a list:

```
with open('myfile.json', 'r') as myfile:    
    json_data = json.load(t)
    for e, v in json_data.items():
        print e, " ".join(v[0]), v[1]
```

This gives:

```
gazelle red blue green yellow gold silver 6
fish bubbles lefty tank goldie 4
Cats whiskers 1
zebra  1
elephant tiny spring 2
Dogs spot 1
```